# Effect of force between 2 charges by insertion of a dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law, dielectric

suppose a positive charge $q1$ at $(-4,0)$ and a negative charge $q2$ at$(4,0)$.say i insert a spherical dielectric of radius $2$ at $(0,0)$ (the shape is arbitrary,the only exception is that it is not an infinite sheet).

now what would be effect on the net force on $q2$.will it increase or decrease?the answer need not be rigorous only an intuitive answer is recquired.

My work-

my physics teacher states that the field decreases in a dielectric but doesnt that happen only inside the dilectric.

but i have read that in a capacitor the dielectric reduces the effective distance between 2 plates.

But bobT's answer in [Does introduction of a dielectric slab between two charges affect the force felt by the charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/572772/)  states that force increases.

And i think of superimposing the field by $q1$ at $q2$.i think that the force increases as the field due to $q1$ remains same,the field due to induced -ve charge at (-2,0) and induced +ve charge at(2,0) on sphere cancel out leaving some field by +ve induced charge behind as that is nearer to $q2$.this add with the field by $q1$ and thus the force should increase.
(this question was asked in a reputed national level high school exam)

I have asked this question before and there are many duplicates but none are formulated well enough to give a satisfactory explanation.so please dont report this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. The force will ultimately increase since the additional effect of the induced positive charge near the negative charge at (4,0).

Comment: @Karthik there is no way my school teacher could be right,right?

Comment: From what you stated in your question, your teacher said the electric field decreases inside the dielectric. This is correct. But your teacher wasn't giving the answer to your question anyways. Your logic is correct.

Comment: Isn't dielectric an insulator whose presence decreases electrostatic force ?